# How can I remove explorer listitem hover tooltips in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to remove this suggestion in VS Code which comes on hover, as it disrupts my scrolling in that I find it visually distracting (it does not literally prevent scrolling).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That area of the UI is called the explorer. What you're seeing is generally called a "tooltip" in UI terminology. Looking through the available settings at the time of this writing, I do not see a setting to disable tooltips for the explorer listitems.

I looked through settings containing "tooltip" and ones starting with `explorer.` and `workbench.list.` and didn't find such a configuration point.

If you open the developer tools with the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` command, you'll see that that particular tooltip is just implmeneted with [the HTML `title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title). The way that it is rendered is up to the browser, which in this case is [chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), and the particular style it appears in differs by platform / OS.

I don't think it's possible to write an extension that removes those title attributes. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview, which states:

> However, we also impose [restrictions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#restrictions) upon extensions to ensure the stability and performance of VS Code. For example, extensions cannot access the DOM of VS Code UI.

What you can do is write a feature-request [issue ticket to the VS Code GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) asking for such a setting to be created to disable these and explaining why you think that would be a desirable thing to have. Bear in mind that for feature-requests to make it into their backlog, it needs to get enough thumbs-up reactions from the rest of the community.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

There is work in progress to make an option to disable/modify that Explorer tooltip, see [A option which can modify the path hover in vscode file explorer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173236) and a good discussion here: [Polish explorer tooltip rendering](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174085).  It quickly got enough votes to get on the Backlog but is being worked on.

There is this setting:

```
explorer.experimental.hover
```

work on this seems to have stopped in early 2023.  For some weird reason, my Insiders Build is not showing that option so that I could test it, so it is unclear to me exactly what it will change.